# Show all possible notification in column instead of stacking on top of each other in Win10

Tags: windows-10, notifications

By default, if an app sends multiple notifications, they are being draw on top of each other, so essentially you ALWAYS have only one notification toast near the tray. What I want is to show as many of them as possible in a column, starting from tray and going up. Is there any way?

Comment: If the notifications have not bee read, it should show you all unread notifications. Read notifications are not shown.

Comment: This happens by default for different applications.  The only time notifications will stack is if they are from the same application.

Comment: I'm not talking about Action Center, read carefully

Comment: If you are talking about Apps, they do not show in columns and the App notifications are in Action Center